# Unable to set the DisplayAlerts property of the Application class

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am intermittently getting the following exception: 
[image]

It does not occur if I step through the code and I'm having trouble working out how to reproduce it reliably. The inner exception is null.

I have search the web and found a C++ MFC programmer cam across the same thing but no answers:
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/555121-unable-to-set-displayalerts-property.html

I also have read up on another possible cause unfortunately is unrelated as its to do with opening a spreadsheet via IE.

> Can someone please shed light on what is going on here? I would much
>   prefer to know the root cause and code around it rather than using a
>   try-catch. Thanks for any advice.

ps I didn't write this code (there would be a bool parameter for true false if I did), I'm just new to this project and want to clean it up a bit and make it more robust.

Comment: You need to add exception handling to capture and report the ErrorCode, as suggested in the troubleshooting tips, then determine what Excel is complaining about. This could be caused by a number of different issues, but without the ErrorCode, you are flying in the dark. Once you figure out the ErrorCode, if it is innocuous you could just trap the exception and ignore it.

Comment: @competent_tech to clarify do you mean the Hex Error Code (that you look up in the OS header file error messages using this) tool: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=985 ? is that what you mean? ps the reason I dont want a Try-Catch is because if I ignore it that would result in removing the msgbox's functionality from spreadsheets

Comment: Yes, the hex error code is returned in the ErrorCode property of the COMException (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) that is thrown in this case. I'm not sure if the message will be in that list you provided, but it certainly doesn't hurt to look there.

Comment: @competent_tech can you put these comments as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add exception handling to capture and report the ErrorCode, as suggested in the troubleshooting tips, then determine what Excel is complaining about.

This could be caused by a number of different issues, but without the ErrorCode, you are flying in the dark. Once you figure out the ErrorCode, if it is innocuous you could just trap the exception and ignore it.

The hex error code is returned in the ErrorCode property of the [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) that is thrown in this case. I'm not sure if the message will be in that list you provided, but it certainly doesn't hurt to look there.